# Nested DLL include configuration in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, dllimport, dllexport

I have a Visual Studio **Solution** containing several projects:

- **Utils** : *DLL*
- **RendererEngine** : *DLL*
- **PhysicsEngine** : *DLL*
- **GameProject** : *EXE*

Here a schema :
[image]

The Renderer and Physics DLLs include the Utils DLL. Everything about the Visual Studio configuration wasn't a problem until I decide to create this GameProject (A Console Application project from Visual Studio). GameProject is going to make instance of exported classes from the Renderer and Physics engines.

If I want to make my GameProject **link** without a problem **I need to include the *include folder* and *.lib* of my Utils DLL project**. And I don't understand why.

Here the VS configuration screenshots :

**Include Conf:**

[image]

**Lib Conf:**

[image]

Is it normal that I have to make an include of a nested DLL in the Visual Studio configuration of the GameProject ? Does anyone had similar problem ?

Comment: Are you aware of the differences between includes (header files), export library files (.lib), static library files (also .lib) and dynamic library files (.dll)? And also between compilation and linking?

Comment: @VTT No problem with that. The .lib that I have to include are import library types. Not static libraries. They are generated only if we specify if we export a class/member or functions with the __declspec(dllexport) identifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your program (.exe) ONLY use stuff declared and/or defined by the interfaces of the dll's then there is no need for your program-build to be aware of anything that those dll's are using in their implementations.

However if anything from your utils-project is made visible in an interface-header of either dll and you use that in your program code ,then you have a depedency from your program to the utils.dll.
Now you need to inform your build environment where to find stuff.

to be concrete:

if you need to include the directory of utils for your build ,then there is a include for a header-file from the utils-project in **one or more** of the headers of `Renderer-` and/or `PhysicsEngine`.

if you need to include the lib-file of utils for your build ,then there is call to **one or more** exported functions (or methods of an exported class) of the `utils.dll`

Solution : sanitize the interface-header files of your dll's

Comment: Thanks @engf-010 . My Physics and Renderer engines include Utils because they need to exploit some specific classes (like a Timer class that I export). Only them are using the Utils stuff not my GameProject (which include only my engines). So I shouldn't have to include the Utils header files in my GameProject?

Comment: Ideally YES. From what I understand from your description ,your dll interface-headers need to be split in two.
First a pure interface-header for the client(s) of the dll's. And a Second header for the internal working of the dll's (this would only be included by the engine sources). An alternative way is moving the includes to utils-header(s) from the engine headers directly in the source-files of your engines.